# ReturnUrl from Form in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have done some research and found that I can use:

```
string retUrl = "";
    if (ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        retUrl =
          ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
    }
```

As a way to set a returnUrl and then pass it into a controller via action link.

However, is there any way I can pass a parameter from a form into a controller?

Here's how my code looks right now:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { returnUrl = retUrl})) {
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

This works great in the sense that it returns you to the right URL when you submit the form. However, the form doesn't actually get saved. If I remove that returnUrl parameter it saves the form but it does not redirect properly.

This reason I'm doing this is because this form is accessible from multiple pages and I don't want to send them all to one page after they submit the form but rather to the previous page.

**EDIT**

I've also tried BeginRouteForm and specifying a controller and action, both approaches did not work.

**EDIT**

Action source:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditReview(Review review, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                reviewRepository.SaveReview(review);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(review);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the source code for the action method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save you form before redirecting you need to switch some lines around in the action method. Instead of:

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
     && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
{
  return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
reviewRepository.SaveReview(review);
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

to

```
reviewRepository.SaveReview(review);
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
     && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
{
  return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("act","contr",FormMethod.Post) {
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl",ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" />
        }
```

There shouldn't be any issue with passing the same in the BeginForm method -- either will bind to `ActionMethod(string returnUrl)`.

Comment: This also doesn't save the form properly for some reason. Funny enough when I did it like this `Html.BeginForm("act","contr",FormMethod.Post, new {returnUrl = retUrl})` it saved the form and redirected but it redirected to a different wrong page.

Comment: Why `{returnUrl = retUrl}` as opposed to letting the view get it out of the context? Does that generate the same result?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are actually changing the `ACTION` method on the form, so I am not surprised it didn't save. I'd get rid of that and just post to the controller/action as you originally intended. Then add the `retUrl` as a hidden input to post along with the rest of the form data.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@retUrl" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    }
```

**Edit:**

You can also use the Html helper.

```
@Html.Hidden("returnUrl", retUrl)
```

Comment: I had high hopes for this, but unfortunately it no longer saved the form properly. My suspicion is that it has to do with the model conflicting with the action's parameters.

Comment: What is the action property on the form, as rendered in the browser? Maybe you still aren't posting to the right controller/action?

Comment: Yeah. I was so convinced that it was my view that was giving me issues that I completely failed to see own silly error in the action. Hours upon hours of programming has that effect sometimes I suppose.